# How to write a big text on Eagle schematic?

Tags: schematics, eaglecad

When you choose a text from the tools bar, and put it somewhere, it will create a text that appears on the pcb.

I would like to create a text just to mark things **on the schematics only**, and I want it big and clear.

1. How do you add a big text to mark things on the schematics ?
2. How do you add a shape, for instance a square, to mark things on the schematic, not pcb ?

Comment: Uh, you use the text and poly tools in the schematic instead?

Comment: [Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1bLB.png) which shows you where the tools on the toolbar are. I've even tested it myself and neither my polygons or text show up on the PCB when I add them in the schematic window.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no lack of research into the basic functionality of the schematic editor in question.

Comment: @Doodle Thanks, but this text is green, small, and there is no way to change it's size/font/etc .

Comment: @Andyaka don't take it too seriously, please, close it :) sorry for bothering but I still can't find solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but this text is green

Because you must change layer you put text into, for example, to "Info".

> and there is no way to change it's size/font/etc

After you place text into schematic, you use info tool on it, and you should be able to change size, ratio and font type in that window. Actually absolutely the same as in board editor.

> So if texts are not transferred between schematics and pcb, why is it matter to set the layer?

Because each layer is having its purpose. If you put text into *Nets* layer (not sure it is correct doing so), EAGLE will treat it as signal, which may need to get wired at the board level (again not sure, never tried this extreme case). Next, you can turn specific layers on and off, it is good practice to put appropriate objects in respective layers so that you can property visualize them.

> I did and it really changed the color from green

There's *Layer settings* icon, you can turn layer visibility in that window, and you can see default layer color there. In general your text changed to gray because you moved text into another layer which identification color is gray.

Comment: Thank you ! I learned something new. So, just to understand, if I won't change the layer to something else, it would appear on the pcb on layout ?

Comment: No. Texts are not transferred between schematic and PCB. It is the mechanism (ie. layer selection) that is the same on the PCB (note that some layers that you see come out in gerbers and some don't).

Comment: So if texts are not transferred between schematics and pcb, why is it matter to set the layer? ( I did and it really changed the color from green)

Comment: Updated answer.